# Solving recurrence $x_{n} = x_{n-1} + n$ with $x_0 = 1$

Tags: summation, recurrence-relations

$x_{n} = x_{n-1} + n$ with $x_0 = 1$
The solution should be $x_n = \frac{1}{2} (n^2 + n + 2)$

This is what I tried:
For homogenous solution, let $h_n = r^n$
$$h_n - h_{n-1} = 0\\ r^n - r^{n-1} = 0 \\ r = 1.$$
So, $h_n = 1^n = 1$.

For a particular solution where the RHS is linear, guess $p_n = an + b$.
So
$$p_n - p_{n-1} = n \\ an+b + a(n-1) + b = n \\ 2an + 2b-a = n$$
So solving, I get $a = 1/2$ and $b=1/4$.

So then the solution is
$$x_n = A(1) + 1/2 n + 1/4$$
where $A = -3/4$.

Comment: $p_n-p_{n-1}=a$

Comment: My bad. So $a=n$. Then the particular solution is $n^2 + b$.  
So then $x_n = A + n^2 + b$. Where does the $n$ come from for the solution given? How do I find a value for $b$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SInce you have $n$ in the rhs, admit that the solution will be a quadratic, that is to say $$x_n=a+b n+c n^2$$ Replace
$$x_n=x_{n-1}+n \implies a+bn+c n^2=a+b(n-1)n+c(n-1)^2+n$$ Expand and group terms to get
$$(2c-1)n+(b-c)=0$$ Since this must hold for all $n$, then $b=c=\frac 12$ which make $$x_n=a+\frac 12n(n+1)$$ and $a$ will be fixed by any given condition.

Comment: How come it would it be a quadratic? I thought that if the RHS is a linear, we take the particular will be a linear and in general if RHS is of degree k, then particular is of degree k

Comment: @Natash1. Think about the method based on successive differences and, I hope, it will be clear.

Comment: Yep, I see it (I think it's because we end up adding "n-1" times of "n")?  
However, I was taught that in general, if RHS is of degree $k$, then the particular solution will be a polynomial of degree $k$ as well.  
How come this doesn't work here? (guessing the particular to be linear)

Comment: @Natash1. If you have $x_{n}=x_{n-1}+n^k$, then $x_n$ will be a polynomial of degree $(k+1)$.

Comment: Thank you. Now I'm unsure about the general case for a polynomial in degree $k$ then. How would you "guess" the particular solution (assuming you didn't see any telescoping sum)?

Comment: @Natash1. Just as I did.

Comment: So if we have  
$a_{n} = \alpha_{n-1} a_{n-2} + \ldots + \alpha_{n-t}a_{n-t} + f(n)$  
where $f$ is of degree $k$, then a guess would be $p_n = b_{n+1} n^{k+1} + b_{n}n^{k} + \ldots + b_0$? (provided the roots of characteristic eqn are distinct)

Answer (score 1):

To solve this recurrence you can use a telescoping sum
$$x_2-x_1 = 2$$
$$x_3-x_2 = 3$$
$$x_n-x_{n-1} = n$$

Summing both LHS and RHS, we get 
$$x_n-x_1 = \sum_{i=2}^ni$$

where both $x_1$ and the sum are well known.

PS: Instead of $x_1$ you can start at $x_0$, the method is the same.

Answer (score 1):

Hint by collapsing sum 
$$   x_n-x_1  = \sum_{i=2}^n    x_i-   x_{i-1}=
\sum_{i=2}^n i =-1+ \sum_{i=1}^n i =-1 +\frac{n^2+n}{2}
$$

Answer (score 1):

$$x_n=n+x_{n-1}=n+(n-1)+x_{n-2}=n+(n-1)+(n-2)+x_{n-3}$$
$$=...=n+(n-1)+...+1+x_0=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}+1=\frac{n^2+n+2}{2}$$